# Grafana behind AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana

- I have grafana running on an EC2 instance on port **3000**
- I created a target group called **grafana-tg** that redirects traffic to the target instances on port 3000
- Configured an ALB with the rule: *if path matches `/grafana` then forward to the target group grafana-tg* (also tried `/grafana/` but still no dice)
- the **root_url** config in grafana.ini:

  `root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/`
- I can see the traffic hitting the grafana service but I'm getting this error message:

  `msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/grafana/ status=404 remote_addr=x.x.x.x time_ms=1 size=22164 referer=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your Grafana is on **EC2:3000/** and not on **EC2:3000/grafana/** correct?

However you’re redirecting from **ALB:/grafana/** to **EC2:3000/grafana/**

- either fix the redirect to go from **ALB:/grafana/** to **EC2:3000/**
- or change Grafana setup to listen at **EC2:3000/grafana/**

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Grafana is listening on port 3000 on the EC2 instance. Apparently, ALB passes the parameter to the target group. I think I might have to configure an nginx reverse proxy on the EC2 instance itself.

Comment: @FrancisV IMO it would be much easier to simply move Grafana to `EC2:3000/grafana/` rather than adding a Nginx to the mix. I’m quite sure there must be a way to set such prefix.

Comment: How? Can't seem to find any documentation that describes this.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to put the url of my Grafana server on line 49 of /etc/grafana/grafana.ini :

- root_url = https://grafana.mydomain.com